# SecureString in MVC

Tags: security, model-view-controller, fortify

My model is like:

```
public string Password { get; set; }
```

And i use it in my repository.cs like:

```
   string somePass= user.pass
                        if (somePass== pass)
                        {
                            return user;
                        }
```

On security scan, this appears to be a heap inspection issue. And it reccomends to use "Secure String"
But when i define the Password parameter as SecureString in my model class and change my repository.cs i get the error.

How can i prevent this to be a security issue?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's referring to the secure string class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.securestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Long story short. A secure string removes its value from memory once it's no longer needed. I've never used fortify, but since your variable name is referring to a password, I'm guessing that fortify sees it as a vulnerability because a password is confidential information that has no reason to be kept in memory once you're done using it.